# how to display the all intervals in colorbar using matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, colorbar

This is my code.I mentioned here 50 intervals,when i drag the slider then only  i got 6 or 7 intervals,but i want to display the all my intervals in my colorbar. So can any one please guide me.Thank you in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import matplotlib.colors
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
img_data = np.random.rand(50,50)

c_max = 2
img = ax.imshow(img_data, interpolation='nearest')
cb = plt.colorbar(img)
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
ax_cmax  = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
s_cmax = Slider(ax_cmax, 'max', 0, 50, valfmt=c_max)
def update(val, s=None):
    # _cmin = s_cmin.val
    _cmax = s_cmax.val
    img.set_clim(_cmax)
    plt.draw()
s_cmax.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `Slider` called `valfmt` should be a string which is used to format the slider value.

So if you wanted to display 2 decimal places to the float you would need to make `c_max = "%1.2f"`. Note that if you want to keep the minimum value at 0 you need to set that too in `img.set_clim(0, _cmax)`

```
c_max = "%1.2f"
img = ax.imshow(img_data, interpolation='nearest')
cb = plt.colorbar(img)
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
ax_cmax  = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
s_cmax = Slider(ax_cmax, 'max', 0, 50, valfmt=c_max)
def update(val, s=None):
    # _cmin = s_cmin.val
    _cmax = s_cmax.val
    img.set_clim(0, _cmax) 
    plt.draw()
s_cmax.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you somuch for you answer,but sir i want to showed to all intervals here i mentioned 50

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by all intervals. Can you exlain in more detail?

Comment: when i drag the slider then only  my remaning intervals are coming but i want to display the whole intervals in colorbar i.e the problem

Comment: yes here s_cmax = Slider(ax_cmax, 'max', 0, 50, valfmt=c_max) here i took 0 to 50 values those values i want to display in colorbar sir

Comment: What should the slider do then, if not to adjust the values on the colorbar (and hence the image)?

Comment: i don't how to adjust the values in colorbar that is the my problem

Comment: Moving the slider in my answer adjusts the value of the colorbar. The limits of the slider are 0 and 50

Comment: can i ask one thing is it possible to drag the colorbar  instead of slider?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182792/discussion-between-navya-sri-and-davidg).